# MySQL IN() function not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a strange problem. IN() function on MySQL database stop to work.

The structure of my table looks like this:

```
| id | name  | categories |
---------------------------
| 1  | User1 | 1, 12, 55  |
---------------------------
| 2  | User2 | 12, 55, 76 |
---------------------------
| 3  | User3 | 1, 55, 76  |
```

To list the users by specific categories I do approximately like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `categories` IN ('1','12','55')
```

or from only one category:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `categories` IN ('76')
```

The problem is that if I ask only one parameter, I get no results. If ask more parameters, then listing only users by the first ID in the list and the other does not.

Before I had no this kind of problem. I do not understand where I make mistakes. Thanks!

### **EDIT:**

Thanks to @Andreas Hauser I finaly get right result.

This is solution:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('76',REPLACE(categories,' ',''));
```

This works exactly as it should.

And other solutions are very smart and helpful, I will use them in the future especially solution from @Justinas and the proposal from @Bilal Rao for search in array of categories:

```
SELECT `u`.* FROM `user` `u` JOIN `category` `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` WHERE `c`.`id` IN ('1', '5', '58');
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: `IN()` expects that your column `categories` only contains a single number.

Comment: You need to normalise your database. Each field should contain only a single piece of information, not a list.

Comment: I want to search in the array specified ID numbers, and display results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use FIND_IN_SET in this case.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('76',categories);
```

This would list all users with the category 76 set.

Comment: Minor point is that FIND_IN_SET needs a comma separated list to search, and in this case the OP has values separated by a comma and a space

Comment: That could probably be solved with a REPLACE put inside the FIND_IN_SET? SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('76',REPLACE(categories,' ',''));

Comment: it could (and I have done so many time before now) but it is an extra overhead. Would be best to just do a replace once to remove the spaces on the table (rather than in the query), but long term a far better solution is to normalise the database, splitting the values off into a different table.

Comment: This is great and exactly what I need. Only I need to remove space between numbers???

Comment: Correct. "UPDATE users SET categories = REPLACE(categories,' ','')"

Comment: Yes, for this to work you need to remove the spaces. Either by updating the table ( _UPDATE users SET categories = REPLACE(categories, ' ', '')_ ) once or by doing the replace as mentioned above by Andreas in every execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

That only works with nummeric fields IDs or exact strings where the value is exast the value your searching for.

You have a comma separated list. That is not really good to fetch the data from that table. When you have a string you have to search with `LIKE`

The Problem with like is that when you search for `%7%` for example you search for 7, 77, 777 too.

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: I worked like that but just becausethat I had a problem with the result.

Answer (score 1):

you have comma separated values in your category column, and **IN** only works on exact match. please create another table and place these comma separated values as **one-to-many** relations. so that you can access them by using Inner Join an IN operator.

Comment: Yes, but on this site user can choose ~100 categories and if you have ~37.000 users * 100 categories, you will have lot of problems on search. That's why I wanted to avoid something like that.

Comment: you can avoid this by making the column as index. but if you go for FIND_IN_SET it will work in LIKE operator way. that's why INNER JOIN is better then Wildcards queries, also FIND_IN_SET takes only two arguments while you can give many arguments in IN operator.

Comment: I will need to redo the plugin completely, it is very complicated searches and I wanted a quick solution but I need to apply this once on the multiple searches option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You `categories` column is of type `VARCHAR` and single cell looks like `"1, 12, 55"`.
`IN` operator is used for single entry per cell. That is if you use `id IN (1, 5, 6)` it will get elements with ID's 1, 5 and/or 6.
Now to search in string, use `LIKE` operator

```
 SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `categories` LIKE "%58%"
```

But it will select any entries that has `58` as component: `1258`, `5864`, `1586` and so on.

Better use pivot tables for that.

```
user_id | category_id
----------------------
    1   |     5
    1   |     6
    2   |     58
```

And than use query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u JOIN category c ON c.user_id = u.id WHERE c.id IN (1, 5, 58)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use this solution for search multiple categories.